# Prove or refute: "If a 3x3 matrix is orthogonal and has det 1, then $\lambda$ = 1 is an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity different from 2."

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

> Prove or refute the following statement:
>
> If a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\cdot3}$ is orthogonal and has det A = $1$, then $\lambda$ = 1 is an eigenvalue of A with algebraic multiplicity different from $2$.

My knowledge of orthogonal matrices is shallow, so I'm not sure how to go about this. I know basic results, such as the determinant of an orthogonal matrix being +/-$1$, orthogonal matrices being symmetric, and how orthogonal matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\cdot3}$ can be written as $A = Q \cdot R = R \cdot Q$, where R is a rotation around some axis $x$ and Q is a reflection along span($x$) if detA = $1$, or Q = I if detA = $1$.

I thought maybe I could deduce something from orthogonal matrices being symmetric, but I can't see that leading anywhere.

My guess is that this is true, and proving it has something to do with the reflection rotation form mentioned above.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Tip: what do the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix satisfy?

Comment: In general, orthogonal matrices are *not* symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Since it is a cubic polynomial, then it has some real root $\lambda$. If $v\in\Bbb R^3$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, then $Av=\lambda v$, and therefore$$\|v\|=\|Av\|=\|\lambda v\|=|\lambda|\|v\|,$$from which you can deduce that $\lambda=\pm1$.

Suppose that the only real eigenvalue is $-1$. There are two possibilities then:

- $A$ has no complex non-real eigenvalue. Then $C(x)=-(x+1)^3$ and so, since $A$ is diagonalizable (since it is orthogonal), $A=-\operatorname{Id}_3$. This is impossible, since then $\det(A)=-1$.
- $A$ has some complex non-real eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then, since $C(x)$ is a real polynomial, $\overline\lambda$ is also a root of $C(x)$, and therefore an eigenvalue of $A$. So, $\det A=(-1)\times\lambda\times\overline\lambda=-|\lambda|^2$, which is also impossible, since $\det A=1$.

So, $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Since it is a root of $C(x)$, which is a cubic polynomial, its algebraic multiplicity is $1$, $2$, or $3$. But it can't be $2$, if it was, $C(x)$ would have to be of the form $-(x-1)^2(x-\eta)$, for some eigenvalue $\eta\ne1$. But the sum of the eigenvalues is real, and therefore $\eta\in\Bbb R$. Since it is not $1$, it has to be $-1$. But then $\det(A)$ would be $-1$.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thank you so much for your answer! I'll have to take some time to digest it.

Comment: Just now got my head around this and learnt a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.